# Regular expression to validate and parse

Tags: regex, validation, parsing

I want to make a regular expression to validate and parse the string below:

```
TESTE_CASE.PESSOAS;CO_CNPJ_CEI BETWEEN (0000000000370000000000, 0000000000370000009999);*
```

Using the following regular expression I can validate the string:

```
\s*\w+.\w+\s*;\s*\w+\s+(?i)BETWEEN\s+\(\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*\)\s*;\s*\*\s*
```

What is the best way to parse this string? I need output like below:

```
String1 = TESTE_CASE.PESSOAS
String2 = CO_CNPJ_CEI
String3 = 0000000000370000000000
String4 = 0000000000370000009999
String5 = *
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose your needed expressions by `()`:

```
( subexpression )
Captures the matched subexpression and assigns it a zero-based ordinal number.
```

and get captured expression by **index**

or use named groups:

```
(?< name > subexpression)
Captures the matched subexpression into a named group.
```

and get captured expression by **name**

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
\s*([^;]+);([^\s]+).*?\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+).*?;(\*)?
```

$1 = TESTE_CASE.PESSOAS
$2 = CO_CNPJ_CEI
$3 = 0000000000370000000000
$4 = 0000000000370000009999
$5 = *

Answer (score 0):

try with this: `(\b(?!BETWEEN\b)[\w.]+\b|\*)`